# Batch export different map compositions based on the same Atlas

Tags: qgis, python, export, atlas, atlas-generator

Assume I have an Atlas with the following elements:

```
'001'
'002'
'003'
```

I also have several compositions named:

```
'A'
'B'
'C'
```

With the print Atlas function, I can print a PDF per each composition, having all Atlas elements: that would produce something like:

```
A.pdf
 - 001
 - 002
 - 003
```

I wish, instead, to export an Atlas element with all compositions as its pages, like this:

```
001.pdf
 - A
 - B
 - C
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to programmatically do this? I've researched plugins and found Maps Printer - its great, but for automating the first process, not the second one. I've come across Python, maybe that's the way to do it?